# A pair of non-degenerate harmonic functions with orthogonal level curves

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

My problem is:

Suppose $u$, $v$ are harmonic in region $\Omega$, and $\nabla u$, $\nabla v$ never vanish in $\Omega$. The level curves of $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular throughout $\Omega$. Moreover, assume $|\nabla u(z_0)| = |\nabla v(z_0)|$ at some specific point $z_0$. Prove that either $u+iv$ or $u-iv$ is conformal in $\Omega$.

Could anyone outline the ideas for the proof?

---

An alternative but closely related problem is: $u, w$ are harmonic and non-degenerate (gradients never vanish) in $\Omega$, and level curves of $u$ and $w$ coincide everywhere. What can you say about $u$ and $w$?

My conjecture is that $u$ and $w$ are proportional. If so, the problem above can be solved by taking the harmonic conjugate of $u$, and deduce that it equals $\pm v$ from the $|\nabla u(z_0)| = |\nabla v(z_0)|$ condition.

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @WillJagy Could you please elaborate a bit? Cauchy Riemann would work nicely for the converse argument, but I don't think it will fit this one (at least I've spent a fair amount of time on Cauchy Riemann in vain before asking).

Comment: What is the angle between a level curve of $u$ and $\nabla u?$

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah, I know, you can turn orthogonality of level curves into orthogonality of gradients. That is $u_x v_x + u_y v_y = 0$. But how can you obtain $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$ from that?

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: @WillJagy You mean this problem? It's a problem in page 59 of this note: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/complex.pdf.

Comment: Do part (a) first. Let $w_x = \lambda v_x, \; \; w_y = \lambda v_y.$ Keep writing.

Comment: @WillJagy Honestly speaking, I've tried that before. Anyway, I gave it another shot just now. I got things like $\lambda_x v_x + \lambda_y v_y = 0$, another orthogonality; and $v_x v_y (\lambda_x^2 + \lambda_y^2) = 0$, indicating $\lambda$ is almost harmonic. But I still fail to see anything particularly interesting. Would you be kind enough to at least give me a hint on what to expect? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Problem 3.4 (a), write $$ w_x = \lambda v_x, \; \; w_y = \lambda v_y \; .  $$

Calculate $w_{xx}$ and $w_{yy}$ and add.

Calculate $w_{xy}$ two ways and subtract.

Comment: Sorry, but that was exactly what I did. The results are $\lambda_x v_x + \lambda_y v_y = 0$ and $\lambda_y v_x - \lambda_x v_y = 0$, from which I got $v_x v_y (\lambda_x^2+\lambda_y^2) = 0$, as I mentioned in the comment above. So unfortunately up till now every "hint" you gave me was what I've tried and failed. Maybe I'm just too dumb to realize anything obvious from there?

Comment: @KevinSayHi  We have three vectors in $\mathbb R^2.$ Call one $P = (\lambda_x, \lambda_y).$ Call one $S = (v_x, v_y).$ Call one $T = (-v_y, v_x).$ What are the pairwise dot products, and what does that tell you?

Comment: Oh, so here is the bottleneck. I really lost all my geometric senses while manipulating those differential equations. Actually after reading your comment I thought quite a while about the level surfaces of $\lambda$ before suddenly realizing we're working entirely in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Yeah I was indeed very dumb. Thank you very much for the help!